# Why would I convert a Java Integer to String using another base(radix) 10?

Tags: java, string

I know in java by default converting an Integer to String uses base 10. Why would I use other bases (2, 8, 16) ??? Are any advantages or disadvantages???

Comment: It depends entirely on your application and what you're trying to do.

Comment: An advantage is if the input string represents a hexadecimal, octal or binary value and you need to convert it to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to write a number as

- binary (base 2),
- octal (base 8)
- hexidecimal (base 16)
- or as a short id (base 36)

> Are any advantages or disadvantages???

Generally, decimal is fine, however sometimes the number either has to be in a particular format or it makes more sense to read it as a power of 2, or in the last case, you want a unique id and you want to short and simple.

Answer (score 1):

An example of when you might want to display the string in another base: Suppose you want to display the RGB values of a color, but as a single "number" rather than the three r,g,b values, i.e. #ffffff000 instead of (255,255,0).
Then you would write the three values in hex (base 16).

Comment: great example. Thanks